# May I ask a question, about Euclid's use of Greek prepositions, on the main site?

Tags: discussion, scope

[A recent answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/69040/21426) referenced Bullinger's *The Companion Bible* quoting Euclid in regard to the use of *eis* and emphasising how Euclid had used the preposition, in a strictly geometric sense, and how this assists with understanding the metaphoric concept associated with the preposition.

I wanted to ask if there is any study of Euclid in regard to the other Greek prepositions, for it is often difficult to determine wherein they overlap and wherein they differ, and it seems to be a good area for study, to catalogue Euclid's usage of all the Greek prepositions.

Were there a Greek language site on SE, I would of course address the matter there. But in the absence of such is it proper to address the question on the main site of SE-Biblical Heremeneutics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but the [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site does take questions on Ancient Greek:

> "We also allow questions about Greek up to the end of classical antiquity, including New Testament Greek. Similarly, questions about small italic languages closely related to Latin are allowed. However, questions should not be asked in these languages. For more details about Greek (and the Bible), see this meta post.

> Questions concerning biblical Latin or Greek should focus more on language than content. For questions about exegesis, philosophy, and to some extent literature, some other Stack Exchange sites might be more appropriate. This is mainly a language site."